# Custom Localized Routes using IApplicationModelConvention are not respected in IUrlHelper.GetVirtualPathData

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm currently porting an application from ASP.NET 4 to ASP.NET Core. I want to use attribute based routing while having the ability to localize the URLs.

The legacy application was using an approach using a custom `IDirectRouteProvider`. Since I didn't find the corresponding type in ASP.NET Core, I went with a solution inspired by https://www.strathweb.com/2015/11/localized-routes-with-asp-net-5-and-mvc-6/. Here's the implementation using an `IApplicationModelConvention`

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc(o =>
            {
                o.Conventions.Insert(0, new LocalizedRouteConvention());
            })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions { ... });

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}

public class LocalizedRouteConvention : IApplicationModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(ApplicationModel application)
    {
        foreach (var controller in application.Controllers)
        {
            foreach (var action in controller.Actions)
            {
                var attributes = action.Attributes.OfType<RouteAttribute>().ToArray();
                if (!attributes.Any()) return;

                foreach (var attribute in attributes)
                {
                    SelectorModel defaultSelector = action.Selectors.First();

                    foreach (var localizedVersion in GetLocalized(attribute.Template))
                    {
                        if (!action.Selectors.Any(s => s.AttributeRouteModel.Template == localizedVersion.Template))
                        {
                            action.Selectors.Insert(0, new SelectorModel(defaultSelector)
                            {
                                AttributeRouteModel = localizedVersion,
                                ActionConstraints =
                                {
                                    new CultureActionConstraint { Culture = ((LocalizedRouteAttribute) localizedVersion.Attribute).Culture }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class LocalizedRouteAttribute : RouteAttribute
{
    public LocalizedRouteAttribute(string template) : base(template)
    {
    }

    public string Culture { get; set; }
}

public class CultureActionConstraint : IActionConstraint
{
    public string Culture { get; set; }

    public int Order => 0;

    public bool Accept(ActionConstraintContext context)
    {
        return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName == Culture;
    }
}
```

Now, this approach works and the localized routes are only available when the correct request culture is set. However, when I use `Html.ActionLink(...)` or any other function that uses `IUrlHelper.GetVirtualPathData()`, the default route is returned instead of the localized one.

As far as I understand, the `IUrlHelper` will check the `IRouteConstraint`s  of a Route but it doesn't seem to respect the `IActionConstraint`. Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to set custom `IRouteConstraint`s in my `IApplicationModelConvention`.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. For now for these particular arctions I am building my uris manually until I'll find a better solution